# Creating image gallery based on picture field and filters

Tags: views, 7

I have two content types ( Man, Woman ) with machine names ( man_type, woman_type ).

They have same fields ( title, url path settings, Body, size, type, price, picture, color ) with different machine names for custom fields ( woman_type_size, man_type_size / woman_type_picture, man_type_picture / .. etc ).

Now i wanna do 2 things :

**1** - Create a Gallery with Views module ( *i think* ) that **only shows the picture field** of the specified type with this kind of url : *( http://website.com/gallery/man,  http://website.com/gallery/woman )*

**2** - Shows pictures based on filters ( like size,color,price ... ) - *that they are already  entered when posting new content* - in the **URL** like this :
**http://mywebsite.com/gallery/man**[indicates type]**/jeans**[indicates clothing]**/black**[indicates color]**/38**[indicates size]**/40**[indicates price]

I am very appreciated if you can help.

Comment: I think one content type is enough. In one content type have other field to indicate that which gender this content belongs to.

Comment: @Mathankumar: how to accomplish it about URLs ?